# Race Condition, smaller request takes precedence over larger Java 8 Asynchronous

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-8, callback, jersey-client

I supply function getArtifactDataList() with a base url and I get back a list of 2 InputStreams. The InputStreams should be different in size as they are very different artifacts I download. However they are the same.

**Code:**

> ```
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
>         <version>2.16</version>
>     </dependency>
> ```

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


private static final String DOWNLOAD_1 = "http://some.random/host/artifact.zip";
private static final String DOWNLOAD_2 = "http://random.other/host/artifact2.zip"


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    List<InputStream> artifactData = getArtifactDataList();

    for(InputStream is : artifactData) {
        System.out.println("Size: "+ IOUtils.toByteArray(is).length);
    }
}

public static final List<InputStream> getArtifactDataList() throws Exception {

    List<InputStream> listData = new ArrayList<>();

    URL downloadUrl = UriBuilder.fromUri(DOWNLOAD_1).buildFromMap(new HashMap<>()).toURL();

    final InputStream data = requestData(downloadUrl); // should be 20MB in size


    URL downloadFontsUrl = UriBuilder.fromUri(DOWNLOAD_2).buildFromMap(new HashMap<>()).toURL();
    final InputStream fontsData = requestData(downloadFontsUrl); // should be 1MB in size

    listData.add(fontsData);
    listData.add(data);

    return listData;
}

public static final InputStream requestData(URL url) {
    Client c = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    WebTarget resource = c.target(url.toString());

    Invocation.Builder request = resource.request();
    request.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);

    final InputStream data =
            request.get().readEntity(InputStream.class);

    return data;
}
```

**Output**

> Size: 1MB
>
> Size: 1MB

It seems the smaller of the 2 request (fontsData) somehow overwrites the bigger of the 2. I little to no idea what is happening. Seems like a race condition, but I don't want to synchronize the requestData function. Is there some other solution which is pretty straight forward to use? Perhaps Java futures or Promises? How to use in my case? Can anyone tell me what is truly going on here? How to fix this?

Edit:
This code is intended to illustrate my issue. I added the streams to the list. Also added the url builder (I don't think this is relevant)

working example

Comment: Note: `URL differentUrl = buildArtifactDownloadUrl(requestDifferentBase);
    final InputStream fontsData = requestData(downloadFontsUrl)` with `differentUrl` vs `downloadFontsUrl`. Also you're not adding the `InputStream`s to the list.

Comment: Also please show the contents of the method `buildArtifactDownloadUrl`

Comment: @Holger  yes edited, the code is to illustrate the issue I'm having. But I added the streams to the list

Comment: @xtratic added url builder code

Comment: Simplifying the code for a question is a good thing, as long as the code still is capable of reproducing the problem. You should not wait for us to check whether the code can reproduce the problem you’ve described, but verify it yourself before even posting.

Comment: @Holger well said

Comment: What does your logger tell you about the URLs you're building.

Comment: When you call `getArtifactDataList("http://some.random/host")` it essentially does this `url = UriBuilder.fromUri(PROTOCOL+"://"+SERVER).path("/some/path").path("http://some.random/host").buildFromMap(new HashMap<>()).toURL();` That doesn't make much sense to me, you already have the protocol and host and a path, but are passing in a protocol host and path again.

Comment: @xtratic that's an excellent point. Let me fix that very quickly

Comment: It's likely that your `getArtifactDataList` was going to the hardcoded url twice, and ignoring the passed in url. When in doubt read your logs. I don't see any issues with race conditions in this code.

Comment: @xtratic aside from the url issues, do you see any potential issues in the manner in which I am calling requestData, like should fontsData wait for data to complete before evoking requestData()? I am out of my element when it comes to async

Comment: @arabian_albert It doesn't look like there's any multi-threading going on so there's nothing to *wait for*. `InputStream data = requestData(downloadUrl)` will be complete before the code moves on to call `InputStream fontsData = requestData(downloadFontsUrl)`. I don't see anything asynchronous.

Comment: the solution to my problem eludes me. What is behavior is causing what I'm seeing? I thought perhaps something underneath the hood of jersey could be asynchronous

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185561/discussion-between-xtratic-and-arabian-albert).

Comment: you should change this `requestData(downloadFontsUrl)` to this `requestData(differentUrl)`